# Evaluate the Time and Space complexity of the algorithm for generating K Combinations of N numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, combinations, space-complexity

I was solving a Leetcode's 77 called "Combinations". Here's the problem statement:

> Given two integers `n` and `k`, return all possible combinations of `k`
> numbers chosen from the range `[1,n]`. You may return the answer in any
> order.

And here's my code:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combine(int n, int k) {
        return combine(1, new LinkedList<>(), k, new ArrayList<>(), n);
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> combine(int start, LinkedList<Integer> comb, int k, List<List<Integer>> result, int n){
        if(k == 0){
            result.add(new LinkedList<>(comb));
            return result;
        }

        for(int i = start; i <= n-k+1; i++){
            comb.add(i);
            combine(i+1, comb, k-1, result, n);
            comb.pollLast();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Although this code was working perfectly fine, but I'm stuck on evaluating the Time and Space complexity for this algorithm.

What would be the Time and Space complexity of the solution presented above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity of the presented solution is **O(k * n! / (k! * (n-k)!))**.

Because the time complexity for this task is naturally bounded by the number of [*`k`-combinations from a given set of `n` elements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations), which can be evaluated using the binomial coefficient:

[image]

And for each generated combination, we need to construct a new `List` of size `k`, all other costs are constant.

Therefore, the resulting time complexity would be *O(k * ( n!/(k!*(n-k)!))*.

And since we need to allocate in memory all `n!/(k!*(n-k)!)` combinations each of size `k`, and there's no additional space required by the algorithm apart from that, space complexity would be also  *O(k * ( n!/(k!*(n-k)!))*.

Comment: and what about space complexity ?

Comment: @KhiladiBhaiyya Since we need to materialize all the combinations as a List of List, the space complexity would be proportional to the size of the combination `k` and the total number of k/n combinations defined by the binomial coefficient, which would also give **O(k * ( n!/(k!*(n-k)!))**

Comment: I asked the same question to ChatGPT and it replied:
The number of recursive calls is proportional to size of input (n) and depth of recursion (k). At each level of the recursion, we make n calls, and the recursion goes k levels deep, so the overall time complexity is O(n^k).

For space complexity, the maximum depth of the recursion stack is k. At each level of the recursion, we need to store the current combination and the start index, which together take up O(k) space. Since recursion goes k levels deep, space complexity is also O(k).
What do you think on this ?

Comment: @KhiladiBhaiyya *"What do you think on this ?"* - It's glaring wrong, I've already explained why. I think you, folks, should put some efforts to stop this wave of hype around ChatGPT instead of inflating it.

Comment: @KhiladiBhaiyya You can try to ask it (in a correct non-offensive way) why it gives so many plain wrong silly answer, you might get a hilarious result which you can share in your blog. ChatGPT has no expertise in any technical, or non-technical area, it can easily confuse Pool of Threads and Pool of Database Connection, as well as it can confidently issue answer the answer that elephant are the creatures that hatches the largest eggs in the world. It's answers worth nothing, it determines key-words in your question and performs a search.

Comment: @KhiladiBhaiyya Only if the question is very straightforward and has well indexed answers on the Web (like "how to create a Spring Boot project") it'll give you an accurate answer, but why would you need it if you right this request yourself and click the first link?

Comment: you are right. When I told ChatGpt that shouldn't the time complexity be O(k * ( n!/(k!*(n-k)!)), it replied "You are right. I apologize for incorrect answer earlier". lmao !!